# Eclipse: Right-Click on some Project shows no "Properties" and "File" --> "Properties" does not work on these projects either. Why?

Tags: eclipse, properties, project

I am unable to click on "Properties" on some projects. After creating certain projects the option to "properties" is shown, but soon vanishes after clicked once. It does not matter what kind of project I create. It works and does not work with some dynamic web projects and normal projects as well.

I was able to link my tomcat server to my projects in a round about way, but I still get the error message in my index.jsp file which is pretty annoying. So to properly link it I need that "properties" to work :/

[image]

[image]

Comment: Does Alt+Enter and via main menu _Project > Properties_ work? Does it work in the current Eclipse version instead of the outdated one you use? Which additional plugins have you installed?

Comment: Look in the .log file in the workspace .metadata directory to see if there are any messages about problems with the Properties entry.

Comment: The menu in the first screenshot is when more than one item is selected (although obviously only one project is selected). Is the correct menu displayed when you (left-)click the project before doing the right-click?

Comment: Hey, thanks for answering:
- Alt+Enter and main menu does not work. It is not greyed out, but it simply opens nothing
- .log just says sth. about angular, but I am not working with angular atm so I guess this is not in regards to my issue
- Do you mean the selection name on the bottom left? Yes the proper project name is displayed

This problem is pretty annoying.. I can run my code, but I have to select the Server each and every time.. furthermore I like a clean code and error/warning messages are annoying ;/

Comment: I cannot reproduce this in Eclipse 2020-06. But I guess it's not because you missed to update Eclipse, but because of a plugin you installed. Can you reproduce it with Eclipse 2020-06 without additional plugins? If yes, delete the `.log`, reproduce the issue and add all of the `.log` to your question.

Comment: My Version is: 2020-03 (4.15.0)
The strange thing is, that there are projects which are not affected. But the last couple of projects are affected. 
The log shows me "java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: angular".
This is cause by the plug-in "org.eclipse.ui.navigator".
This is strange as well, cause I am not doint anything with angular. Just Tomcat Servlets and Hibernate. Should I just delete the plug-in?

Comment: Please try if you can reproduce this with Eclipse 2020-06 without additional plug-ins. It sounds like a plugin (which you may not even remember you installed) extends the project properties (by an "angular" field, page or section) and this fails (probably, it's not caused but happens in the extended Eclipse Navigator plugin). But to know this for sure, one would have to know the `.log` file containing the full stack trace. Please add it to your question.